# JavaScript - Return Function not invoking

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am having a problem with a function (Kendo event handler) not being invoked - I have highlighted with debuggers below.

The second debugger in FuncTwo is not being hit, and I am unsure why - is someone able to assist? Thanks.

Kendo event:

```
// FuncOne is called fine
// FuncTwo is called, but not invoked?
$.extend(kendoOptions, { change: function (i) { FuncOne(i); FuncTwo(i); } });
```

FuncTwo:

```
function FuncTwo(i) {
   // this is being hit
   debugger;
   return function (e) {
      // this is not being hit
      debugger;
   }
}
```

Comment: The returned function is not being invoked.  It's just being returned.

Comment: `FuncTwo(i)()` would invoke it.

Comment: you don't do anything with the return.

Comment: Isn't this what FuncTwo(i); is doing?

Comment: No, FuncTwo creates the second method and returns it.  Function definitions are not immediately invoked.  You have to invoke it.  It's the exact same behaviour as all other function declarations.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Seems obvious now - Thank you!